# single tpl.php file for two nodes?

Tags: nodes

In my Drupal7, I have same piece of code in tpl.php files for two different nodes. My tpl.php files are following:

```
page--node--9.tpl.php
page--node--11.tpl.php
```

Since code is same for both pages, it is possible to create a tpl.php file for both nodes? I mean something like

`page--node--9and11.tpl.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `template_proprecess_page` hook to achieve this as shown below:

```
function <THEME_NAME>_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (arg(0) == 'node' && in_array(arg(1), array(9, 11))) {           
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'][] = 'page__node__9and11'; //For page--node--9and11.tpl.php
    }
}
```

Add above code to `template.php` of your theme & clear cache.

Comment: How can I use this code but for 'html--node--9.tpl.php' instead of 'page-node--9.tpl.php'?

Comment: Replace **page** word with **html** in the code given. Means use **template_preprocess_html**

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x

Answer (score 0):

I think isn't an elegant solution but it works for me:

- Create a tpl `page--node--11.tpl.php`.
- And put inside an include of the other template `<?php include( 'page--node--9.tpl.php' ); ?>`