# Create just one .tpl.php file for several nodes?

Tags: 7, theming

I created these .tpl.php file for two node:

html--node__39.tpl.php
html--node__14.tpl.php

**Question**: can I create just one file for both node?, something like:

html--node__39&&14.tpl.php

Comment: I found this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/151214/single-tpl-php-file-for-two-nodes which is just what I need but but for 'html--node--9.tpl.php' instead of 'page-node--9.tpl.php'?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to change the template dynamically on node type with a preprocess function. Of course you can also use this based on nids. https://www.drupal.org/node/1142800

Answer (score 1):

You can create template file for your node type `node--yournodetype.tpl.php`

or 
`node--your-node-type.tpl.php`. It depends on your node type name.
In that template you can create a condition just for two nodes with defined node ids. EG:

```
<?php if (in_array($node->nid, array('39', '14'))): ?>

<?php // Code just for predefined nids ?>

<?php else: ?>

<?php // Code for all other nodes of this type ?>

<?php endif;
```

It's just a proposition, of course, you can use above mentioned variants:

`function <THEME_NAME>_preprocess_node($variables){ 
     if (in_array($variables['node']->nid, array('39', '14'))) {            array_push('node__template_nnn', $variables['theme_hook_suggestions']); 
  } 
}`

Comment: Not a fan of this solution, hard to maintain. It's better to create one template and load it when you need it in a preprocess function.

Comment: Of course, it's just a proposition, you can use above mentioned variant:

function <THEME_NAME>_preprocess_node($variables){
if (in_array($variables['node']->nid, array(9, 11))) {           
        array_push('node__template_nnn', $variables['theme_hook_suggestion']); 
    }
}